# QML TableView: how to bind to selection.onSelectionChanged()

Tags: qt, qml, tableview, qt5, qt-signals

I know how to bind to root TableView signals like `onClicked`, but since `onSelectionChanged` is a signal of its `selection` property, I'm not sure how to bind to it.

I thought for sure I could use `Connections` to bind to it, but the following code didn't work:

**EDIT**: `Connections` actually does work, the problem was unrelated mistakes (see my own answer)

```
    TextArea {
        id: messageDetailTextArea
        readOnly: true
        font: messageListDialog.font

        function update() {
            var selectionText = ''
            messagesTable.selection.forEach(function(rowIndex) {
                var row = model.get(rowIndex)
                if (row && row.message) selectionText += row.message
            })
            text = selectionText
        }

        Connections {
            target: messagesTable.selection
            onSelectionChanged: update()
        }
    }
```

But unfortunately, the `TextArea` doesn't update when I click on a row in the table.  How can I respond to a selection change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, so I didn't have `model` and the call to `update()` properly qualified.  This worked:

```
    TextArea {
        id: messageDetailTextArea
        readOnly: true
        font: messageListDialog.font

        function update() {
            var selectionText = ''
            messagesTable.selection.forEach(function(rowIndex) {
                var row = messagesTable.model.get(rowIndex)
                if (row && row.message) selectionText += row.message
            })
            text = selectionText
        }

        Connections {
            target: messagesTable.selection
            onSelectionChanged: messageDetailTextArea.update()
        }
    }
```